# My boardgame account is missing in the account overview

Tags: support, status-completed, profile-page

When I take a look at my profile page, I see all my accounts listed on the different sites of the stackexchange network, except for my account on Board and Card Games. The site is in public beta so it should show up. Can anyone confirm this behavior with his/her account? Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cleared your account associations and then reset them.  For future reference, you can do this using the buttons at the bottom of your accounts tab in your profile.

Comment: Thx, works like a charm!